# Plotting Fisher's Iris Dataset with colorcode

Tags: julia

I want to plot something like [Fisher's Iris Dataset](http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Fisher.html) With Sepal length (y) against Sepal width (x) and colorcoding type. There is a screenshot from Julialang's homepage with minimal sourcecode: [image]

Which I suspect originates from [Gadfly's demo](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/demo.md), but since I'm new to the language I have no idea how this works. How can I reproduce the plot from scratch?

Comment: on which platform? i seems you are using a tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but to reproduce the plot you posted, you can do more or less exactly what is shown in the IJulia code cells (although the screen grab could be a little out of date, given that the example [in the Gadfly docs](http://dcjones.github.io/Gadfly.jl/) is called slightly differently). In any case, you can just start a REPL and do:

```
using RDatasets, Gadfly
plot(dataset("datasets","iris"), x="SepalWidth", y="SepalLength", color="Species")
```

This should open a new tab in your browser, containing precisely the plot in the first output cell.

(NB: This assumes that you have RDatasets and Gadfly installed, otherwise you have to `Pkg.add()` them first obviously.)

Comment: Worked thanks! I was confused by the error from calling `data` which seems obsolete.